# update Firebase emulator function timeout duration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When emulating firebase functions locally is there a way to change the function timeout from the default 60s?

`--idlePruneInterval` has been added as an option to the google cloud emulator CLI: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/66

This option <strike>doesn't appear to work</strike> is not officially supported in either the firebase serve mode:

```sh
firebase serve --only functions --idlePruneInterval=5000
```

or the experimental shell emulation:

```sh
firebase experimental:functions:shell --idlePruneInterval=5000
```

Is there another way around this problem? Perhaps editing a config file?

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Functions emulator from Firebase is separate from the one provided by the Google Cloud Platform org. The command line parameters from one won't necessarily work on the other.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Is that to say this isn't possible at all? From what I could tell the firebase emulator wraps the google cloud one: when I install firebase-tools I get a warning to make sure google cloud emulator has been uninstalled/reinstalled properly

Comment: The Firebase emulator wraps the GCP emulator, but not their CLI. This means it needs to pass arguments explicitly, and `idlePruneInterval` is not one of the arguments it currently passes on.

Comment: With regards to the question - and acknowledging the lack of official support, is there anything else that can be done to achieve the same effect? i.e. manually editing a config, etc.?

Comment: I heard from a reliable source that PRs are the most effective way to ensure your favorite feature gets added. E.g. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/564

Comment: Haha .. thank you for the insight! But I was really looking for a proven workaround I could use today. If I get around to doing it myself I will definitely pay it back with a PR :)